# Column data disappear on row selection in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My Jqgrid looks like below.When i select particular row my Images column data disappear.When i click other row,the data of previous row appear again.Kindly tell me how to fix it.
**Before Click:**
[image]

**After Click:**
[image]

After Click on row, the images in `Actions` and column before `Name` disappear.When i click on another row these images appear again just like before click.My colmodel is is follow:

```
 $("#list_Alerts").jqGrid({
        datatype: function (gridData) {
            BindAlertsGridData(gridData);
        },
        colNames: ['','', '<input type="checkbox" id="cbox" onclick=checkBox(event) />', 'Name','E-Mail Address', 'Agency', 'Status', '','Actions'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'ApprovedFlag', index: 'ApprovedFlag', width: 25, align: 'left', resizeable: false, formatter: checkStatusFlag },
            { name: 'user_id', index: 'user_id', align: 'left', hidden: true, resizable: false, key: true },
            { name: 'Check_Box', editable: true, index: 'Check_Box', width: 25, align: 'left', resizable: false, edittype: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false }, editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: checkboxFormatter, sortable: false },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150, align: 'left', resizable: false, formatter: fontColorFormat },
            { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 150, align: 'left', resizable: false },
            { name: 'Agency', index: 'Agency', width: 220, align: 'left', resizable: false },
            { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 70, align: 'left', resizable: false  },
            { name: 'Blocked', index: 'Blocked', width: 25, align: 'left', resizeable: false,formatter: checkStatus ,sortable:false},
            { name: 'Actions', sortable: false, edittype: 'select', width: 90, align: 'left', sortable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return "<div id= action_" + rowObject[1] + " class='action'><div style='float:left;margin-left:2px;margin-right:5px'><a class='ui-icon ui-icon-check' href=#" + rowObject[0] + " title='Approve'></a></div><div style='float:left;margin-left:2px;margin-right:5px'><a class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' href=#" + rowObject[0] + " title='Edit'></a></div><div style='float:left;'><a class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');\" title='Delete' href=#" + rowObject[0] + "></a></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"; }, resizable: false }],
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [2, 10, 20, 50],   // page size dropdown
        pager: jQuery('#pager_Alerts'),
        pgbuttons: true,           
        viewrecords: true,        
        pagerpos: 'right',
        recordpos: 'left',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        sortorder: "asc",
        sortname: "user_id",
        loadtext: "Loading",
        width: 755,
        hoverrows: false,
        gridComplete: function () {});
```

Kindly tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: It's clear that you have some CSS problems: you should just take a look on the pager input element. Your icons looks not like standard, there are no right borders on the calls, ... So you use definitively some custom jQuery UI CSS and some other additional CSS styles. You should post more full code of your page or just prepare a demo which demonstrates the problem (in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example). You use `datatype` as function which is not good way in the most cases and you don't use `gridview:true` option which makes the grid slowly.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg ..it's definitely a `css` problem,and been fixed.

Comment: You are welcome! I still strictly recommend you don't use `datatype` as function and use `gridview:true` in all your grids. You should use `pager: '#pager_Alerts'` instead of `pager: jQuery('#pager_Alerts')`. Consider to use `height: "auto"` too, remove all `align: 'left'` and all `index` properties from `colModel`. If you have some common column properties you can change default value of the property. For example you can add jqGrid option `cmTemplate: {resizeable: false}` and remove `resizeable: false` from all columns of `colModel`.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg.I will follow your instructions.You save my time.:)